# Error: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type str which has no callable sqrt method" while using pandas for creating a formula for a column

Tags: python, pandas, formula

I have a dataframe and I'd like to create a formula using square root and multiplication in a column. I've tried the below script and it's not working.

```
import numpy as np
ufo['Grid Spacing(m)']=''
ufo['Area'] =ufo['Grid Spacing(m)'].apply(np.sqrt).multiply(0.866)
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about "not working"?  In the code above `ufo` is empty, so there's nothing to take the square root of.

Comment: Please provide the error code you are getting